# IOS Appium can not make scroll with Touch Action method

Tags: ios, scroll, appium

I have tried with following method to make scroll down from top to the bottom on the screen but it seems not responding at all. Do you have any idea what is the reason ?

public void scrolTest(){

```
    TouchAction tc=new TouchAction(driver);
    Dimension dimension=driver.manage().window().getSize();
    Double screenHeightStart = dimension.getHeight() * 0.5;
    int scrollStartY = screenHeightStart.intValue();
    Double screenHeightEnd = dimension.getHeight() * 0.2;
    int scrollEndY = screenHeightEnd.intValue();
    int scrollX=dimension.getWidth()/2;
    tc.longPress(scrollX,scrollStartY).moveTo(scrollX,scrollEndY).release();     //(0,scrollStartY,0,scrollEndY,2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using perform() method.

```
tc.longPress(scrollX,scrollStartY).moveTo(scrollX,scrollEndY).release().perform();
```

Try this code

```
public void scrollTest() {
    Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int scrollStartY = (int) (dimension.getHeight() * 0.5);
    int scrollEndY = (int) (dimension.getHeight() * 0.2);
    int scrollX = dimension.getWidth() / 2;
    int heightOffset = scrollStartY - scrollEndY;

    //Also note that in moveTo function, you have to provide the offSet values, not the (x,y) coordinates
    //of the point where you want to move. Hence, i have written 0 in x coordinate (as we don't want to 
    //change x coordinate) and calculated the heightOffset separately.
    new TouchAction(driver).press(scrollX, scrollStartY).moveTo(0, heightOffset).release().perform();
}
```